# How to start an Android Studio to have that window?

Tags: android-studio

I wanted to start learning a programming language and checked for Java tutorial. But I got stuck at the start and can't get through. On the tutorial, a person teaching starts with a window with a hello world that you can see in his code and in the console, but when I start Android Studio and create new project there is completely another window, and even if I modify a code and click run, it is virtual device starting the run, not the text I can see in the console. What do I do to create a window that I can just write a code into and see effects in a console, not a virtual device? It may be very trivial but is very annoying because I just do not know what to do even so it is just a start.

What I want :

[image]

What I get :

[image]

Comment: It is because you are using Android Studio which is modified version of IntelliJ IDEA made specially for Android Development. If you want to learn JAVA use IntelliJ IDEA or you can go through @Basi answers for every JAVA sample you create in Android Studio

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why you use Android Studio? `You can use Netbeans or Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA and the other if you want the result after the run in window or console.`
**In the android studio, the result is in emulator android like the apps name. ANDROID Studio.**
I hope you can understand my answer.

Comment: wow man, actually the program he used was IntellIJ even so he didn't say so in the video and the layout is similar so I didn't notice that, well..thanks

Comment: _no problem bro_

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps

- In the dropdown-view select [Project View](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html)
- Remove include `':app'` form `settings.gradle`
- Remove app directory
- click `Refresh all Gradle projects`
- Replace `build.gradle` with

  ```
  apply plugin: 'java'

  sourceCompatibility = 1.8
  version = '1.0'

  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
      testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
  }
  ```
- Configure `src` and Child Directories `main`, `java`, `fooo and`foo.java` Class > Add in main 
  class to construct code and print results

  `public static void main(String[] arg) {
          String hi = "Hello World";
          System.out.println(hi);
  }`

[image]

- Select Edit Configuration from drop down menu where normally you start project
- Click Add new Configuration and select Application

[image]

- Run the project you will get it